# How many different combinations of a 4 digit sequence with only 3 numbers as input

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Looking for a way to calculate how many permutations of the numbers 1,5,9 with the output being a four digit number. For example:

1159
1195
1519
1559
1591
1595
1951
1915
1999

Each of the three numbers **must** be used for the permutations, so no 1111,5555,9999, or 1155, 1199 etc. All three digits must be used.

EDIT - For some reason the question is closed because there is no context provided, but in the hopes that I can clarify this, I will provide that now.

I am making a video game where the player will need to take a series of clues to determine what the right combination of numbers is to proceed to the next area of the game. I wanted to ensure there weren't too many permutations that it would be too time consuming for the player to input them all if they had to.

[image]

I hope this satisfies the issue of context and how this applies to why I am asking this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternative:

$$\binom{3}{1} \times 4 \times 3. \tag1 $$

In (1) above, the first factor refers to selecting one of the three elements in the set $~S = \{1,5,9\},~$ to become the element that will be repeated.

Then, in (1) above, assuming that the duplicated element is eliminated from further consideration, the second factor refers to the four possible positions that will be occupied by the lowest (remaining) element of the set $~S.~$

Then, in (1) above, with two of the elements in the set $~S~$ eliminated from further consideration, the third factor refers to the three possible remaining positions that will be occupied by the last remaining element in the set $~S.~$

Once the two *singleton* (i.e. not duplicated) elements from the set $~S~$ are positioned, the two positions that will be occupied by the duplicated element from the set $~S~$ are fixed as the last two remaining positions.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at it in the following way. Since you've got three numbers and four places you could put them in you need to choose one number that will be in there twice. For example let's take $1$ as that number. You can arrange them in the following ways $\text{1 1 _ _ }$, $\text{1 _ 1 _ }$ and  $\text{1 _ _ 1 }$ when $1$ is in the first place and the other $1$ is on the right of it, if $1$ is in the second place and the other $1$ is on the right you can have: $\text{_ 1 1 _ }$ and $\text{_ 1 _ 1}$. Lastly you can put them as: $\text{_ _ 1 1 }$. Meaning there are six ways to do this.
 This is more commonly calculated as $\binom{4}{2}$, since you have 4 places and two digits to put them in, where the order of those two digits doesn't matter, since in this case they're the same. 
Now other than $1$ there are two more numbers two choose from. So you multiply $\binom{4}{2}$ with $3$ (Beacause all the orderings we have for $1$ we also have for $5$ and $9$). After you do this there are two places left to fill in, in which you can put two numbers that you have left. In the first place you left you can choose two numbers and in the second only one number that you haven't used yet.

So the final solution is $3\cdot\binom{4}{2}\cdot2\cdot 1=36$.

Answer (score 1):

A number like  $1159$ has $\frac{4!}{2!}$ permutations, but you need to *choose* the "double" digit, thus

$3*\frac{4!}{2!} =36$