# How many different combinations exist with 5 inputs and 2 outputs?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I asked a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4828312/how-many-different-combinations-of-a-4-digit-sequence-with-only-3-numbers-as-inp) to help me build a clue in a video game that I am developing for a personal project, but this time the calculation is significantly different than the last.

## Preface and Context of question

I am no math wizard, that is why I am here seeking help. I am simply a game hobbyist with an ambition to add puzzles to my game, but before creating any puzzles for this game I must consider the difficulty that is created when x number of combinations of numbers are made accessible to the players.

## The Question

I am looking for a way to calculate how many different combinations of 2 digit numbers there are when using 5 numbers as input. Players are essentially tasked with combining 2 of the 5 numbers to create a 2 digit number.

There are several added variables when making the calculation:

- there are **no doubles** allowed.
- Players must choose 2 of the numbers out of the 5 that are listed **without using duplicates**.

So lets look at various examples:

Numbers to choose from are: **1 2 3 4 5**

Possible 2 digit combinations are:

```
12
13
14
15
21
22
23.... etc
```

As stated above, players will **not** be allowed to use duplicates:

```
11
22
33.... etc
```

Lastly, the calculation should treat combinations of numbers with identical numbers that are in different order as the same thing. For example:

`12` should count the same as `21` when adding up the amount of possible combinations.

Answer (score 1):

You may be asking about [combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination). The ways to choose two elements out of five is denoted $(^5_2)$ pronounced "five choose two". The explicit formula is $\frac{5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1}{(2 \cdot 1)(3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1)}$.

You can type this query directly into Wolfram Alpha if you forget the formula e.g. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=5+choose+2

Comment: 5 choose 2 is the 'magic formula', but you need to understand the detail. We have 5 choices for the 1st digit, So 4 remaining digits, and 4 remaining choices for the 2nd digit. $5 \times 4=20$. At this step $ab$ or $ba$ are considered as different, so we need to divide by 2. Final result is $10$.